# Use same DataGridView in multiple pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have two aspx pages:

1. **DashboardPreview.aspx:** This is the homepage. It shows **top 5 dashboards** in a DataGridView. It shows other information too.
2. **DashboardList.aspx:** It shows **all the dashboards with pagination** in a DataGridView.

There are several controls available for each dashboard (i.e. for each row of the DataGridView). For example: a dashboard can be "edited" and "shared" with other users.

I would like to code the DataGridView **only ONCE**.

Then, I would like to use that code in both the pages. How do I do it?

*Note: I create DataGridView by dragging and dropping it from Toolbox of Visual Studio i.e. I did not code the entire thing myself. However, I did create controls like "Share" button myself.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reuse a server control across pages then you need to create a User Control.

To create a User Control:

1. I would create a specific folder for user controls.
2. Right click that folder and select "Add New Item" and then select User Control.
3. Enter the GridView inside of that User Control

Your User Control will look something like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="YourUserControlName.ascx.vb" Inherits="Controls_YourUserControlName" %>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1">
    <!-- Do you grid view stuff here -->
</asp:GridView>
```

To use a User Control you need to register it on the page you want to use it on. The code looks like this:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/ucGrid.ascx" TagName="ucGrid" TagPrefix="uc" %>
```

Then you would use it just like a server control.

```
<uc:ucGrid ID="GridView" runat="server" />
```

However, registering the User Control on every page can become tedious, so to make things easier you can register them in your web.config.

```
<system.web>
  <pages>
    <controls>
      <add tagPrefix="uc" src="~/Controls/ucGrid.ascx" tagName="ucGrid"/>
    </controls>
  </pages>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. I will accept your answer after I use it successfully. Thanks again!

Comment: It worked. But I have a little problem. The ascx file I created contains DataSource and a grid view. For one file I would like to edit the DataSource to read only 5 rows, while for another file, I would like it to read all the rows. Now how do I access the datasource from new file (i.e. from the file where the ascx is being used at)?

Comment: You can extend your User Controls to have properties. Using those properties you can set the data source dynamically.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will write setters and getters for the properties and try to modify the inner elements of the User Control.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to put the grid in a UserControl, then include the UserControl on all the relevant pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "web user contorl" for it. Add a webusercontrol into your solution drag and drop a datagridview into the webusercontrol interface and change the codebehind file of the usercontrol based on your needs. After that build your solution. After building your solution you can just drag and drop your usercontrol to any page that you want to use. You will not have to code it again and again. You can search for "using web controls" if you need more details.